# Trying to get property 'admin' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to avoid ordinary users to see what's in my dashboard but it says "Trying to get property 'admin' of non-object" when i try to Auth the user
here what the error says[enter image description here][1]

**User Model**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'admin'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];


    public function profile() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Profile');
    }

    public function posts() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }
}
```

**Route**

```
Auth::routes();



Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function(){

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Comment: where I can add the other pictures Im just new here

Comment: Edit your question and add the code you are having trouble with.

Comment: where i can add the other image sir Dave so it would be clear

Comment: Don't add pictures, add text.

Comment: What does `$user()` look like

Comment: `var_dump(Auth::user());` to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should be sure that the `Auth::user()` method returns something.

Meanwhile, you can change the line 110 to:

```
<?php if (Auth::user() && Auth::user()->admin): ?>
```

Comment: yeah you're right sir Silvio Delgado but how do i know that the Auth::user() is working? im just new in laravel and I'am  just to trying teach my self how to code

Comment: @John if you don't know if Auth::user() is returning something, my example code will satisfy your needs. ;-)